# HSQLDB and NetBeans 8.0.1?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, hsqldb

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.1 and I need a HSQLDB for a project in school. I was following [this tutorial](http://tech.aniketvast.com/2009/11/hsqldb-netbeans.html), but unfortunately I got the following error message:

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/ using org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver (java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server)
```

Can someone please help me? I tried it with HSQLDB 2.3.2.

Comment: You probably want to use the URL for embedded usage, not to connect to an already running server (which is a separate process outside of your application or NetBeans). See the manual for details: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess

Comment: Oh ok, so where do I find this server-application and who do I set it up correctly?

Comment: See the next chapter in the manual: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes But I'm pretty sure you don't want the server mode if you don't know what it is. Just use the embedded mode.